# Facebook Graph Request for user friends is returning an empty array

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

So I am developing an app that uses the FacebookSDK.  When I try to request the user's friends however, I receive an empty array.  I know that you can only access friends who have also approved you app/permissions (And I did allow the access to friends list for both people that have used the app).  There are two users on my app, myself and a test user, but for whatever reason the JSONArray is empty in the Graph request response.  Does anybody know what is going wrong?  Here is my code:

```
    AccessToken fbAccessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    GraphRequest userFBFriendsGraphRequest = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(fbAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onCompleted(JSONArray returnedObjArr, GraphResponse response) {

             Log.e("JSONArray", "The completed json array is " + returnedObjArr);

        }
    });

     Bundle requestParameter = new Bundle();
     requestParameter.putString("fields", "id, name, picture");
     userFBFriendsGraphRequest.setParameters(requestParameter);
     userFBFriendsGraphRequest.executeAsync();
```

Thank you for the help ahead of time.

Comment: Both users granted user_friends permission to the app? If you do the query in Graph Explorer does it work there?

Comment: I was using AWS and had to go into that SDK and change it manually.  I was trying to update the permissions directly from my SignInActivity, but because I am actually authenticating through the AWS service, I had to go directly into their to alter the source code.